# How to read and process binary (base-2) logical representations from file

Tags: python, shell, binary, awk, decimal

I have a file containing 800 lines like:

```
id       binary-coded-info
---------------------------
4657     001001101
4789     110111111
etc.
```

where each 0 or 1 stands for the presence of some feature.
I want to read this file and do several bitwise logical operations on the
binary-coded-info (the operations depend on user input
and on info from a second file with 3000 lines). Then, 
these re-calculated binary-coded-info should be written to
file (with trailing zeros, e.g.

```
4657     000110011
4789     110110000
etc.
```

How should I do this without writing my own base conversion routine?
I am open for anything, also languages I do not know, like python, perl, etc. And it should work without compiling.

So far, I tried to script, awk and sed my way. This would
mean (I think): batch read as base-2, convert to base-10, do bitwise operations depending on user input and second file,
convert to base-2, add leading zeros and print. The usual console hints
to use bc do not seem elegant because I have many lines in a file.
The same holds for dc.sed. And awk doesnt seem to have an 
equivalent to flagging input as binary ( as in "echo $((2#101010))"  ),
and also, the printf trick doesn't work for binary. So, how would I do this
most elegantly (or, at all, for that matter) ?

Comment: What kind of bit-wise operations? Do you need to check for masks, or always just single bits?

Answer (score 3):

Why convert them and use bit operations?

In Python, you can do all of this as a string.

```
for line in myFile:
    key, value = line.split()
    bits = list(value)
    # bits will be a list of 1-char strings ['1','0','1',...]
    # ... do stuff to bits ...
    print key, "".join( value )
```

Comment: You can also convert the items in bits to bools with: bits = [n!='0' for n in bits]  This way you can just say if bits[2]:...

Answer (score 1):

In python, you can convert to binary using int, specifying base 2.  ie:

```
>>> int('110111111',2)
447
```

To convert back, there is a `bin` function in python2.6 or 3, but not in python2.5, so you'd need to implement it yourself (or use something like the below):

```
def bin(x, width):
    return ''.join(str((x>>i)&1) for i in xrange(width))[::-1]

>>> bin(447, 9)
110111111
```

(The width is the number of digits to pad to - your examples seem to be using 9-bit numbers.)

Answer (score 0):

In C, you can use "strtol(str, NULL, 2)" to do the conversion, if you're already doing this in C.

Something like the following would work:

```
FILE* f = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
char line[1024];
while ((line = fgets(line, sizeof(line), f))
{
  char* p;
  long column1 = strtol(line, &p, 10);
  long column2 = strtol(p, &p, 2);
  ...
}
```

You'll need to add error-handling, etc.

Answer (score 0):

"Simple" Perl one liner (replace foo bar baz quux with your flags

```
perl -le '@f=qw/foo bar baz quux/;$_&&print($f[$i]),$i++for split//, shift' 1011
```

Here is a readable Perl version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#flags that can be turned on and off, the first 
#flag is turned on/off by the left-most bit
my @flags = (
    "flag one",
    "flag two",
    "flag three",
    "flag four",
    "flag five",
    "flag six",
    "flag seven",
    "flag eight",
);

#turn the command line argument into individual
#ones and zeros
my @bits = split //, shift; 

#loop through the bits printing the flag that
#goes with the bit if it is 1
my $i = 0;
for my $bit (@bits) {
    if ($bit) {
        print "$flags[$i]\n";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Brian's answer:

```
# Get rid of the '----' line for simplicity
data_file = '''id       binary-coded-info
4657     001001101
4789     110111111
'''
import cStringIO
import csv, sys
data = [] # A list for the row dictionaries (we could just as easily have used the regular reader method)
# Read in the file using the csv module
# Each row will be a dictionary with keys corresponding to the first row
reader = csv.DictReader(cStringIO.StringIO(data_file), delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace = True)
try:
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row) # Add the row dictionary to the data list
except csv.Error, e:
    sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (filename, reader.line_num, e))
# Do something with the bits
first = int(data[0]['binary-coded-info'],2) # First bit string
assert(first & int('00001101',2) == int('1101',2)) # Bitwise AND
assert(first | int('00001101',2) == int('1001101',2)) # Bitwise OR
assert(first ^ int('00001101',2) == int('1000000',2)) # Bitwise XOR
assert(~first == int('110110010',2)) # Binary Ones Complement
assert(first << 2 == int('100110100',2)) # Binary Left Shift
assert(first >> 2 == int('000010011',2)) # Binary Right Shift
```

See the python docs on [expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) for more information and [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv) for more information on the csv module.

Answer (score 0):

And following a long tradition, here is a awk version :-)
Last checked on gawk 4.0.1
Should work for other awk as well.

```
{
      var = _int("00010101",2);
      print _bin( or( var ,  _int("00101001",2) ) , 8 ) 
      print _bin( and( var , _int("10110111",2) ) , 8 ) 
      print _bin( xor( var ,var ) , 8 );
}    

# convert var to d-ht base. Specify 16 for hex, 8 for oct, and such. Up to base 36, for fruther base, provide X. if d<=36, and wish to use custom X, provide 1 for i.
function _obase( v , d , X , i, this , r ){
  if(d<=9){r="";while(v){r=v%d""r;v=int(v/d)};return r;}
  if(d<=36&&!i){for(i=0;i<=9;i++)X[i]=""i;for(;i<d;i++)X[i]=sprintf("%c",55+i);}
  r="";while(v){r=X[v%d]""r;v=int(v/d)};return r;
}
function _pad(d, p, w, this ,r){
  r=""d;while(length(r)<w)r=p""r;return r;
}
function _bin( v , w , this ){
  return _pad(_obase(v,2),"0",w);
}
# convert string to var, using d as base. for base>36, specify X. if wish to use custom X, provide 1 to i
function _int( s , d , X , i , this , k , r ){
  r=0;k=length(s);if(d<=9){for(i=1;i<=k;i++){r*=d;r=r+int(substr(s,i,1));}return r;}
  if(d<=36&&!i){for(i=0;i<=9;i++)X[""i]=i;for(;i<d;i++)X[sprintf("%c",55+i)]=i;}
    for(i=1;i<=k;i++){r*=d;r=r+X[substr(s,i,1)];}eturn r;
}
```

function and(), or(), xor() may be missing on some type of awk.
If so, load the bit manipulation libs. There are some for awk floating in the net.
Or provide your own.